# Why does engine temperature remain high with lights switched on?

Tags: lights, temperature

I've just replaced a radiator only to find the coolant gone and car overheating again.

When I switched the engine off(but first turn of key was still on) I noticed the temperature gauge just wasn't going below normal regardless of how long I waited.  However after I switched car lights off I noticed it gradually went down to the cool or cold point.

So why does keeping the lights on cause the coolant temperature reading to stay high or the engine to stay hot even though it's not running?

Comment: That sounds very strange - almost certainly an electrical issue causing a false reading IMO - what make/model?

Comment: @motosubatsu I think it could be that I was becoming impatient/not waiting long enough for the temperature to go down and the coincidentally when I turned the lights off it went down rapidly. I've only just learnt that it takes a long time for temperature to go down. thanks.